# How to connect multiple nodes located on different server with the elasticsearch java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, connect

Here is how i have set up my 2 nodes for the cluster "elasticsearch" :
  - Node 1 stored on an ip 10.80.10.183 port 9200
  - Node 2 stored on an ip 10.80.10.184 port 9200

i would like to know which address i have to specify in the method addTransportAdress with the port 9300 because i want that if the node 1 is down, the node 2 will be still accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify all your nodes in transport client, like this:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.80.10.183"), 9300))
    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.80.10.184"), 9300));
```

Comment: It should be port 9300.

Comment: there is no way to put only one address  that link theses two nodes ?

Comment: You need to specificy **both** transport addresses since **both** nodes need to communicate with each other.